# What's the purpose of std::dynamic_extent in std::span

Tags: c++, std, std-span

I know `std::span` is static. It is just view over bunch of vector/array/etc. elements.

I see [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) of span, and it seems like `std::dynamic_extent` is used in 4-6. But in those constructors, there is a required template parameter for the size - `std::size_t N`. To me this means that the size/count/len is known at compile time. So what really is `std::dynamic_extent`?

Comment: Is the answer something more than “you can use `std::span` with _or without_ a size known at compile time”?

Comment: @DavisHerring I think they're asking how `std::span` can have a dynamic extent when the size template parameter `std::size_t N` always needs to be specified at compile time.

Comment: yep @DavisHerring , that's exactly I was wondering. Confusing API!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of [`std::dynamic_extent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/dynamic_extent) is

```
inline constexpr std::size_t dynamic_extent 
    = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
```

It's a special value of a `std::size_t` that's used to indicate that the `std::span` has a dynamic extent.

> There is a required template argument for the size - `std::size_t N`. To me this means that the size/count/len is known at compile time.

The "size" of the `std::span` is still specified at compile time, it's just that when the "size" takes on that special value, it's treated as a dynamic extent.

Comment: Ah that's one confusing API. Thx

Answer (score 0):

The constructor would set the initial size, but when span has dynamic_extent, its size might evolve

```
std::array<int, 4> arr{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::span<int> s{arr}; // whole array view     // size is 4
s = s.subspan(1, 2); // restricted array view // size is 2 now
```

Comment: In that case my new `s` has again new size - 2. If I had: `auto s2 = s.subspan(1,2)` then s2 would be static_extent. (I should try this!)

Comment: `s.subspan<1, 2>()` would return static extent. `s.subspan(1, 2)` returns dynamic extent.

Comment: yep! I see now.